# Python: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I try to use pip to install `sklearn`, and I receive the following error message:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\13434\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\tests\data\openml\292\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1-status-deactivated.json.gz'**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not install packages due to an OSError: \[WinError 2\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66322049/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-winerror-2-no-such-file-or-direc)

Answer (score 35):

Run CMD in administrator mode and enter:

```
pip install sklearn --user
```

and Done!!

Comment: --user working for me

Comment: Life saver! pip install tensorflow --upgrade --user solved my issue.

Comment: sklearn is deprecated, use "scikit-learn" instead

Comment: This Does Not work for Linux Mint.

Answer (score 25):

I had exactly the same issue installing this package on my Windows laptop - then read of the 260 character limit. I followed this guide - and after rebooting, successfully installed 'sklearn':

https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/

Comment: Now Package is installed but while importing the package I am getting error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why would anyone restrict path lengths by default? Silly Windows :P

Comment: Better to [summarize the link for when it goes down in the future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Answer (score 10):

Try `sudo pip install` 'package name' `--user`

Comment: This method also giving an error in venv.  `ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.`

Comment: Go to the ``pyvenv.cfg`` file in your Virtual environment folder and  set ``include-system-site-packages = true`` and save the changes. Afterwards reactivate the virtual environment.

Otherwise, try the command I gave without ``--user`` This may also work

Comment: Yes pip install flask-restful --user  Its worked... thanks

Comment: What does the `--user` command do?

Comment: The use of "--user" is useful if you want to install packages for a specific user without having to be logged in as an administrator. This can be useful if you do not have permissions to install packages system-wide, or if you create a virtual environment for your Python project and want to install the package only in that environment without affecting the system.

Answer (score 3):

I removed and reinstalled Python and then entered this into my terminal command line:

pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip install --upgrade pip

and it fixed my issue.

pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip install

and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by doing

```
conda install google-pasta
```

this directory under envs/xxxx/Lib/site-packages/ was not having METADATA. Likely to be partial installation.

Answer (score 1):

keep package up to date.I upgarde my pip and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed similar issue when I installed tensorflow:

1. On your search box, Search for: "Registry Editor"
2. Open this path["Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRGNP.jpg)

3. Looking for this file: [change the value from 0 to 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeXx9.jpg)

4. then restart your computer

Further study: "https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/#:~:text=In%20Windows%2010%20Pro%20or%20Enterprise%2C%20hit%20Start%2C,%E2%80%9CEnable%20win32%20long%20paths%E2%80%9D%20item%20and%20double-click%20it."

Answer (score 0):

If Windows is 8.
You need to change your access policy inside Python3 repository where all packages, including PIP.

"Properties" -> "Security" -> select a user -> select "Change" and everything below.
Next, update PIP (py -m pip install --upgrade pip) and install the packages inside ENV

Answer (score 0):

For me issue was with the long paths support for Windows.
And here they suggest the solution and worked fine for me.

[Windows Fix Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later)

From the above source this is the final solution

> The registry key Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled (Type: REG_DWORD) must exist and be set to 1

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by enabling Windows Long Paths support by following these steps:

Open the Group Policy Editor by running gpedit.msc in the command prompt.
Go to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem.
Find the Enable Win32 long paths policy and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

This same error can also happen when using a `requirements.txt` if the file isn't formatted correctly, with an output that might resemble:

```bash
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Processing /private/tmp/pygments-20230806-6216-4zajry/Pygments-2.16.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/tmp/pygments-20230806-6216-4zajry/Pygments-2.16.1'
```

Recreating this file with `pip freeze > requirements.txt` fixed this for me!

Answer (score 0):

So i deleted my venv, restarted my machine, then i created a new venv, finally everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to solve it was pretty easy at first run PowerShell in the administrator mode then type in this command New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" `
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force then restart your PC and run your pip install command and everything should work Note: I got this info from "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=powershell#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later" for more info visit the website.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

The steps here fixed it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKYRcwbFp6Y . The step is basically to change the include-system-site-packages to true in pyvenv.cfg file in your virtual env folder

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32591608)