# Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, numpy

I try to use pip to install numpy, and I receive the following error message:

> Python: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> 'c:\python39\Scripts\f2py.exe' -> 'c:\python39\Scripts\f2py.exe.deleteme'

I'm not sure about an older version of numpy installed first.

I ran just command prompt, not a one with admin privileges.

[image: Here is a command prompt in the picture]

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Exactly how did you install numpy?  Show us the command line.  How did you run it?  Did you have an older version installed first?  Did you run it from an elevated command prompt?  You've done something out of the ordinary, because f2py is part of Numpy and has worked for many tens of thousands before you.

Comment: I put a picture with installation process of numpy etc.

Comment: Does numpy work?  If you do `python` and `import numpy`, does it work?  Perhaps someone installed this for you.  If not, you may have to run this as an administrator.

Answer (score 216):

Try running the command as administrator:
or
`pip install numpy --user` to install numpy without any special previlages

Comment: yep. Running as admin worked for me.

Comment: For Windows: running cmd as administrator, this works for me

Answer (score 79):

I had the same problem with other packages. Just try

```
pip install 'package name' --user
```

and see if the issue is resolved. It worked out for me.

Answer (score 21):

I know its a bit late, however there maybe users still having the same issue.
This is mostly a priviledge issue. You need to install numpy with as Admin.

1. Open command prompt, and Run as Administator

[image]

2. Now install numpy

   `pip install numpy`

[image]

and you should be good to go...

Answer (score 14):

It seems like the package you are trying to install already exists, or you don't have privileges to install it.

1. First, try to `import numpy` and use it. If it doesn't work, try the second option.
2. Try to `install numpy` again with user privilege by running the command below:

   ```
   pip install numpy --user
   ```

Answer (score 8):

It's a privileges issue. In my case, there was a `wheel.exe` error popping up while force installing `tensorflow_gpu`. I escaped it by adding `--user` at the end of the command.

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu --user
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem while trying to install some packages.  To resolve the problem, I added `py -m` before `pip install`.

For example:

```
py -m pip install requests
```

Or on a Mac computer

```
python3 -m pip install requests
```

Comment: This worked for me and the other solutions above did not.

Comment: Worked for me as well

Answer (score 6):

The problem doesn't appear to be specific to numpy, and an elevated administrator prompt worked for me. I used [gsudo](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo) to elevate a normal powershell prompt for the packages I was installing (which happened to include numpy).

Here's a sample session (with some parts elided with `...` for brevity):

```
PS > pip install -r pkgs.txt
Collecting black
  Using cached black-22.3.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting bs4
...
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, attrs, ...
  WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system can
not find the file specified: 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\normalizer.exe' -> 'C:\\Py
thon310\\Scripts\\normalizer.exe.deleteme'
```

The fix:

```
PS > gsudo pip install -r pkgs.txt
Collecting black
  Using cached black-22.3.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting bs4
...
Installing collected packages: certifi, websockets, ...
    Running setup.py install for path-and-address ... done
    Running setup.py install for docopt ... done
    Running setup.py install for bs4 ... done
Successfully installed Flask-2.1.1 Markdown-3.3.6 Pillow-9.1.0 PuLP-2.6.0 ...
```

Answer (score 6):

Run the python command(s) in a **command prompt** with Administrator privileges

Note: To open the command prompt with Administrator privileges

1. Press the Win + R on your keyboard.
2. In the Run dialog box, type “**cmd**” into the field and then press Ctrl + Shift + Enter
3. Allow it to run in elevated privileges

Answer (score 5):

I know its a bit late to answer this but this is what worked with me

1. run CMD as administrator
2. run this command pip install tensorflow --user

thats what worked with me.

Answer (score 4):

Adding `--user` to the command resolved the issue for me

`pip install --upgrade openai`

became

`pip install --upgrade openai --user`

and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing an error while Installing InstagramScrapper
I fixed it as follows:

```
pip3 install instagramscraper --user
```

it works for me

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the C/python/Scripts directory properties, the folder was marked as read-only. Changing that fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

You just simply add `--user` after line. This is the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

For me creating a virtual environment and activating it resolved it.

Creating a virtual environment -

```
python3 -m venv virtualenvname
```

**Activate the virtual environment**
On Linux, Unix or MacOS, using the terminal or bash shell:

```
source /path/to/venv/bin/activate
```

e.g. source virtualenvname/bin/activate

On Unix or MacOS, using the csh shell:

```
source /path/to/venv/bin/activate.csh
```

On Unix or MacOS, using the fish shell:

```
source /path/to/venv/bin/activate.fish
```

On Windows using the Command Prompt:

```
path\to\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

On Windows using PowerShell:

```
path\to\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

**Deactivating the virtual environment**
On Linux, Unix or MacOS, using the terminal or bash shell:

```
deactivate
```

On Windows use the Command Prompt:

```
path\to\venv\Scripts\deactivate.bat
```

On Windows using PowerShell:

```
deactivate
```

This answer is for those who may use a different OS.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63442886)

Then install any package you need.

```
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

I also just encountered this. For me, it was because I forgot to activate my conda environment, which had numpy installed.

Check the answer recommending you try importing numpy and try that out. If numpy is unavailable, but you've installed numpy before, then most likely you have installed it either on another version of Python (one can have multiple versions installed - check your active version by typing `python --version` on the command line), or on a particular conda/pyenv/venv/other environment you forgot to activate.

For more info on Python package managers (which are out-of-scope for the question), see this guide: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-conda-environments-bc6180fc533

Either way, you should be able to install/reinstall numpy, and get the f2py.exe file on your activated python installation and environment.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve the error is to install the package scoped to the current user, without requiring elevated privileges. Try this out

```
pip install beautifulsoup4 certifi cffi charset-normalizer --user
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in win 10, but it wasn't numpy that seems to have been the problem.

I was installing using `pip install pyev3` saw this issue and came here.

I ran `pip uninstall numpy` then `pip install pyev3` - no change, still failed.

I checked with `pip list` and numpy had been installed, so I then ran `pip install hidapi`, which worked and then ran `pip install pyev3` which also then worked.

Hope this helps if you have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command prompt as administrator

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command prompt as administrator works for me too while installing django using the command `>> pip install django`

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for your answer! It looks like this solution was already suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68556246/497934). Consider upvoting that one instead if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case deleting `python` folder from `c:\users\(username)\appdata\roaming\` solved the issue because I've python already installed in `c:\` drive root directory.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, right click on Python folder (mine is c:\Python311) and add your current user as owner with access rights onto the folder in the Security panel.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error in VSCODE while I was creating a chatbot I tried running "pip install tensorflow" in the terminal almost 8-9 times and I figured out it was giving me a different error every time and after running the same script the error was solved.[image: error 1]
[image: error 2]
[image: error 3]
[image: solution]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error using pip to install a different package on my Windows machine. The fix was to add the path to the python Scripts folder (C:\Python311\Scripts) to the PATH environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just Open command prompt as "Administator", then pip install any packages