# I received the following error msg when I tried installing Spacy:

Tags: python, spacy

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python311\\Scripts\\weasel.exe' -> 'C:\\Python311\\Scripts\\weasel.exe.deleteme'
```

My Code:

```
from spacy import displacy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

I tried importing spacy

Comment: Try to create a virtual environment and install the spacy package..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66322049/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-winerror-2-no-such-file-or-direc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not install packages due to an OSError: \[WinError 2\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66322049/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-winerror-2-no-such-file-or-direc)