# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Did not find Pillow-9.4.0.dist-info\\METADATA

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-import

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\home\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib\\site-packages\\Pillow-9.4.0.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

I have a program that requires Pillow to be installed. Hence, I have a try and except block where I import the modules.

```py
Loaded = False
while Loaded != True:
    try:
        from PIL import Image
        import os,sys,time
        Loaded = True
    except:
        print("\n[ERROR] An error occured while loading libraries\nAttempting to download libraries...")
        from os import system
        system("pip install Pillow")
```

I get the same error while installing it from CMD.

```
C:\Users\home>pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\home\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (9.4.0)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\home\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib\\site-packages\\Pillow-9.4.0.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

Then I tried doing what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980952/python-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or) post did.

```bash
pip install Pillow --user
```

However, the results have not changed, it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by just deleting the dir `c:\\users\\home\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib\\site-packages\\Pillow-9.4.0.dist-info\`