# Ive installed and have issues with the install for twilio and other issures

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, twilio

I've did the pip install for Twilio and the terminal did most of the install but at the end it gave me in install error code:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\sip\domain\auth_types\auth_type_registrations\auth_registrations_credential_list_mapping.py'
```

I don't know what I've tried I'm still learning
I've did other pip install and nothing is working is my install not working right I've pulled or searched for the file location and its there but its still not working do I need to do the install
manually and yes I'm running Python 3 the last version and I'm on Windows not Mac

Answer (score 0):

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980952/python-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or), try the following:

```
pip install twilio --user
```